# Как исправить утечку памяти?

Tags: c, память, утечка-памяти

Есть код:

```
char * str = strrem("test_string", "s");
str = strrem(str, "_");
printf("%s\n", str);
```

`strrem`:

```
char * out = calloc(strlen(_str), 1);
...
return out;
```

Как можно исправить утечку памяти, оставив функцию `strrem` чистой.

Comment: Вызов free() добавьте...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, если бы все было так просто. Когда переменной `str` присваивается новое значение, я теряю доступ к старому (в этом месте и есть утечка). Если вызвать `free(str)` до операции присваивания, то я не смогу получить значение перменной `str`.

Comment: А вы так не делайте, не перезаписывайте указатель на выделяемую память. И не освобождайте память, пока она вам нужна.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, тогда каким образом переменная `str` получит новое значение?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов не проще код в ответ написать?

Comment: @Eanmos а зачем(!) ей новое значение? Вы записали в нее указатель на выделенную памятью. Если вы его перезапишете - не сможете освободить. Вы определитесь: переписывать указатель и иметь утечку или не переписывать и не иметь.

Comment: @tCode напишите. Я не могу писать код, когда от него требуются взаимоисключающие вещи, да еще и непонятно зачем.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, не перезаписав указатель я не смогу изменить переменную `str`, не используя промежуточных, конечно, вот я и спрашиваю, можно ли избавиться от утчеки памяти.

Comment: @Eanmos Нельзя при таком подходе: вы выделили память, вы и освобождайте. А перетирая указатель вы теряете информацию, необходимую для освобождения памяти. И, самое главное, совершенно не ясно зачем вы все это делаете.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, хм, хорошо. Тогда как устранить утечку, используя промежуточные переменные?

Comment: char* toFree = str; после того как в str будет указатель на выделенный буфер. И free(toFree) когда старое значение уже не нужно. Но я не советую вам так делать, пока вы не разберетесь что вы и зачем таким образом делаете. А то будете долго ловить падения.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, может, посоветуете как **нужно** делать и просвятите меня на счет падений?

Comment: @Eanmos повторю: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/561096/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b8?noredirect=1#comment729545_561096

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, может Вы просто не понимаете, чего я хочу. Попытаюсь объяснить еще раз. Функция `strrem` возвращает указатель на строку. Память для этой строки выделенна через `calloc`. Как я могу очистить память (и, таким образом избежать утчеки) выделенную изначально для строки `str`?

Comment: @Eanmos free(str) определенно очистит память, выделенную через calloc(), как и было сказано с самого начала.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, прошу прощения, сам запутался. Исправил комментарий, прочтите еще раз.

Comment: @Eanmos Вносите изменение в вопрос: в чем конкретно проблема, чего вы хотите достичь и так далее. char * str = "simple_string"; - эту память выделять НЕ НАДО, утечки тут НЕТ.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, прошу прощения, наверное, изрядно потрепал Вам нервы. Если честно, не думал, что там не утечки. Изменил вопрос. Думаю теперь все станет понятнее. Память для `str` теперь выделяется в куче.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char * str = strrem("test_string", "s); //Ошибка синтаксиса, не соберется.
str = strrem(str, "_");
```

Учитывая что strrem() выделяет память через calloc() и strrem() вызывается дважды, у вас должно быть ДВА указателя для хранения выделенной памяти, чтобы потом вызвать free() для обоих.

Например так:

```
char* str = strrem(...);
char* ptr1 = str;
str = strrem(...);
... //Тут аццкей кодес
free(str); //освобождение от первого strrem
free(ptr1); //освобождение от второго strrem
```

Answer (score 1):

Так и не понял, что в точности `strrem()` делает со своими аргументами, но предположим, что на их основе создает некий результат (строку) в динамической памяти, который и возвращает.

При этом Вы не хотите освобождать память (вызывать `free()`) первого аргумента внутри `strrem()` (возможно из-за того, что иногда это константа), не хотите писать "лишние" строчки кода, а всегда хотите иметь возможность использовать такую запись:

```
str = strrem(str, arg2);
```

и избежать утечек памяти.

Обобщая идею в ответе @Владимир Мартьянов,  все это (в основном экономию строчек) можно реализовать примерно так:

```
char *str, *prev = 0;
....
str = strrem("xaxa", "xoxo");
...
while (...) {
  free(prev), prev = 0; // не забудьте обнулять, чтобы потом не упасть от повторного освобождения той же памяти
  str = strrem(prev = str, "abc");
  ... 
  // кстати, тут доступны как старое (в prev), так и новое значения str
}
...
free(str);
free(prev); // поскольку мы обнуляем prev после free(prev), то это безопасно
```

Т.е. в тех местах, где Вы вызываете `strrem()` с аргументом, память которого далее должна быть освобождена, Вы сразу (в точке вызова) запоминаете этот адрес.

При желании (и имея перед глазами больше разных случаев использования `strrem`) все такие вызовы с освобождением желательно оформить в виде макросов (при достаточном их разнообразии скорее всего переменную `prev` вообще удастся убрать с глаз долой).